# The easiest way to subclassing C# System.Type

Tags: c#, .net, types, subclassing

I need to make fixed point number class inherit from System.Type.

```
class FixedPoint : Type
{
    public bool Signed { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int IntegerWidth { get; set; }
    public FixedPoint(Boolean signed = false, int width = 16, int integerWidth = 8)
    {
        Signed = signed;
        Width = width;
        IntegerWidth = integerWidth;
    }
}
```

When I tried to compile this code, I got error messages saying that I need to implement methods as Type is abstract class.

```
userdef.cs(3,7): error CS0534: 'FixedPoint' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Type.GUID.get'
userdef.cs(3,7): error CS0534: 'FixedPoint' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Type.Namespace.get'
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
userdef.cs(3,7): error CS0534: 'FixedPoint' does not implement inherited abstract member
        'System.Type.AssemblyQualifiedName.get'
```

How can I avoid those error messages? Is there any easy way to subclass Type? Do I have to implement all the methods? If so, are there any references for doing that?

Or

Is the work of subclassing Type worth trying? I do need to subclass Type for some reasons, if it's really hard to do it. I'd better give up early to find another way.

Comment: **Why** do you need to subclass `Type`? Please explain, because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sounds a little wild, why do you need to subclass System.Type?

Comment: You should be subclassing `Type` only if you are trying to extend the current reflection system (or implementing your own, I suppose.) Otherwise, you can just declare a new `struct`, no inheritance required.

Comment: Looks like you were trying to do something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you have your reasons for inheriting from `System.Type`, even though I agree with @mootinator, here are some answers to your other questions:

> Is there any easy way to subclass Type?

No.

> Do I have to implement all the methods?

Yes.

> If so, are there any references for doing that?

You add the `override`-keyword to each of the `Properties` and `Methods`

This is an example of how you start off, you need to `override` each of the `abstract` properties and methods.

```
public class Test : Type
{
    public override Guid GUID
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

This is a complete compileable `class` that overrides all the `properties` and `methods` that is needed, but nothing is implemented.

```
public class Test : Type
{
    public override Guid GUID
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool IsDefined(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override object[] GetCustomAttributes(bool inherit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override string Name
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    protected override bool HasElementTypeImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override object[] 
           GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override Type UnderlyingSystemType
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override Type GetElementType()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override bool IsCOMObjectImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override bool IsPrimitiveImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override bool IsPointerImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override bool IsByRefImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override bool IsArrayImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override System.Reflection.TypeAttributes 
                       GetAttributeFlagsImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] 
           GetMember(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return base.GetMember(name, bindingAttr);
    }
    public override Type 
           GetNestedType(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] 
           GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override System.Reflection.PropertyInfo 
              GetPropertyImpl(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, 
                              System.Reflection.Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, 
                              System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] 
           GetMembers(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override Type[] GetNestedTypes(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.EventInfo[] GetEvents()
    {
        return base.GetEvents();
    }
    public override Type[] GetInterfaces()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override Type GetInterface(string name, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.EventInfo[] 
           GetEvents(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] 
           GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.EventInfo 
           GetEvent(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.FieldInfo 
           GetField(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] 
           GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override System.Reflection.MethodInfo 
              GetMethodImpl(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr,
                            System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConvention, 
                            Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo[] GetConstructors(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected override System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo 
              GetConstructorImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
                                 System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, 
                                 System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override Type BaseType
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override string AssemblyQualifiedName
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override string FullName
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override System.Reflection.Assembly Assembly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override System.Reflection.Module Module
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override object 
           InvokeMember(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, 
                        System.Reflection.Binder binder, object target, object[] args, 
                        System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers, 
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, string[] namedParameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**These are the properties gets that you need to implement**

- GUID
- BaseType
- AssemblyQualifiedName
- Namespace
- FullName
- Assembly
- Module
- UnderlyingSystemType
- Name

**These are the methods that you need to implement**

- InvokeMember
- GetConstructorImpl
- GetConstructors
- GetMethodImpl
- GetMethods
- GetField
- GetEvent
- GetFields
- GetEvents
- GetInterface
- GetInterfaces
- GetEvents
- GetNestedTypes
- GetMembers
- GetPropertyImpl
- GetProperties
- GetNestedType
- GetMember
- GetAttributeFlagsImpl
- IsArrayImpl
- IsByRefImpl
- IsPointerImpl
- IsPrimitiveImpl
- IsCOMObjectImpl
- GetElementType
- GetCustomAttributes
- HasElementTypeImpl
- GetCustomAttributes
- IsDefined

As you can see, there are quite a few that you need to override in order to remove all the compilation errors, so either you have a really good reason for wanting to do this or you should think about overriding from another class/struct or just create a new class/struct.

Comment: @prosseek, no problem, I just went crazy with my hot keys here having the compilations errors on one screen and the code on the other :) Just to point something out, if you don't intend to implement all of the methods, make sure you write a lot of tests and that you document it, so that others that use your code don't run into weird errors.

Answer (score 5):

If what you are trying to do is create a new value type, just use `struct` instead of `class` (no subclassing `Type` required).

Otherwise, what is it you want to accomplish by subclassing `Type` which you can't do with `typeof(TypeName)`?